# The system show error message in the same grid at the end (last column)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've working on a project where I'm importing customers data from .Csv file and then after reading the file load data in a grid (HTML table). I've set some checks on the values if there format are wrong so then it's shows error at the end column of table.
Now I Want If a file is not validated, the system should show error messages in the same grid at the end (last column). In this case show a prompt to the user "There is some error in data, please check the last column of the grid for further detail"
So how can I do that?

Here I'm loading the data in a grid and validating it.

```
 var NoOfColumn = FileDataArray[0].length;
                $("tbody").empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < FileDataArray.length; i++) {
         var tr = "<tr>"
   $.each(FileDataArray[i], function (i, v) {
                        tr = tr + "<td>" + v + "</td>";
                    })
                    tr = tr + "</tr>";
                    $("tbody").append(tr);
                                                   }
                var cntrl = $("#dialog-ProductLoader-div");
                cntrl.dialog("close");
               
                for (var i = 0; i < FileDataArray.length; i++) {
                    if (i != 0) {
                        
                        for (var j = 0; j < FileDataArray[i].length; j++) {

                            if (FileDataArray[i][0] == null && j == 0)
                                alert("Customer Name is Mandatory");

                            if (FileDataArray[i][1] == null && j == 1) {
                                alert("Customer Type Name Input is mandatory");
                            }
                            if (FileDataArray[i][2] == null || FileDataArray[i][2] == "No" && j == 2) {
                                FileDataArray[i][2] == false;
                            }
                            if (FileDataArray[i][2] == "Yes" || "yes" && j == 2) {
                                FileDataArray[i][2] == true;
                            }
                            if (FileDataArray[i][3] == null && j == 3) {
                                FileDataArray[i][3] == 0;
                            }
                            if (isNaN(FileDataArray[i][3]) && j == 3) {
                                alert("Credit Limit value must be numeric")
                            }
                            if (FileDataArray[i][4] == null && j == 4) {
                                FileDataArray[i][4] == 0;
                            }
                            if (isNaN(FileDataArray[i][4]) && j == 4) {
                                alert("Opening Balance value must be numeric")
                            }
                            if (FileDataArray[i][5] != ("Male" || "male" || "female" || "Female" || "other" || "Other" || "") && j == 5) {
                                alert("Error");
                            }
                            if (isDate(FileDataArray[i][6]) && j == 6) {
                                alert("Error")
                            }
                            if (isDate(FileDataArray[i][7]) && j == 7) {
                                alert("Error")
                            }
                            var mailformat = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
                            if((!mailformat.test(FileDataArray[i][9]) && j == 9)){
                                alert("Email is invalid")
                            }

                           }
                          
                             
                          }
                }
```

And Here is View

```
<div class="customertable">
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
         
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="loaderBody">
      
    </tbody>
</table>
    </div>
```